# Does QScopedPointer hide multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having trouble accessing the private part of a PIMPL design. "Of course!", you say! you're supposed to be! 
Well, I'm writing some functional tests, so I don't care that I'm accessing private members, ok? :-)

To get to the point,  I have the public class set up with a QScopedPointer to the private implementation as follows;

```
class CV {
...
private:
  QScopedPointer<PrivateCV> const _d_ptr;
  PrivateChartView * d();
  const PrivateChartView *d() const;
};
PrivateCV * CV::d()
{ 
  return _d_ptr.data(); 
}

const PrivateCV* CV::d() const
{ 
  return _d_ptr.data(); 
}
```

and the private bit looks like this:

```
class PrivateCV : public QObject, public Ui_CVForm
{
  Q_OBJECT 
  friend class MyTestClass;
public:
  ...
public slots:    
  void do_something();
}
```

It seems that MyTestClass can access the do_something() member function of PrivateCV, which it obtains as follows (pseudocode, obvs):

```
CV *cv = MyApp::get_a_cv();
PrivateCV *pcv = cv->d();
```

i.e. it will call this fine:

```
pcv->do_something();
```

but I can't access anything that is on the Ui_CVForm (the generated UI class from uic). 
Ui_CVForm is (in part) as follows:

```
class Ui_CVForm
{
public:
    QGridLayout *gridLayout_2;
    QGroupBox *groupBox;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
};
```

Is this something to do with the const-ness of the function d(), or the QScopedPointer perhaps?
When I'm inside CV, I can access the ui form elements of the PrivateCV with no problems..

```
void CV::and_another_thing()
{
  d()->lineEdit->setText("wtfa");    
}
```

any pointers (pun intended) most welcome!

Comment: do you have a header of the ui form pulled to where you are trying to access its stuff?

Comment: To access private members you could A) make the test class/function a `friend`. B) use g++'s `-fno-access-control` option (not that I recommend it in general, but it *can* be useful for tests).

Comment: Urgh I guess it could be as simple as the header. I thought I'd get compilation problems (doffeeent Ines!) if it couldn't see the ui header though. I'll try later.

Comment: The class I'm accessing from is a friend of the private implementation and the public one already, (that's why I can access the d() function). besides, the parts I'm trying to access of the private class are public!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this turned out to be due to some idiot (me) using the same filename for two different classes in different libraries. 
The test library was picking up one header for Ui_CVForm which didn't contain items like the lineEdit above, while PrivateCV was using another... hence no complaints about not seeing the header at compile time.